# Zend in my local Xamp

Tags: zend-framework

I have an old site in Zend framework. I have downloaded all the files from the server. I want to modify the site. So I need to set up this project in my local system. I have created a folder named "NFL01" within my XAMPP/htdocs/projects. But I got an error message when I run the project (http://localhost/projects/NFL01/). See the error message

> "C:\xampp\htdocs\projects
>   Warning: require_once(Zend/Config/Xml.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\NFL01\index.php on line 26
>
> Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required 'Zend/Config/Xml.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\pear\;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/application/config;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/application/models;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/application/controllers;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/library;C:\xampp\htdocs\projects/public_html') in C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\NFL01\index.php on line 26"

I don't know what's happening there?
need to setup anything in my XAMPP or is there is any other problem.

Please reply in details

Many many Thanks

Comment: you need to add the folder containing `Zend` to your include path... typcially this is `/path/to/project/library`

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have the **zend library** copied to the library folder in the root of you project. You also need to setup you **application.ini** file correctly:

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules = ''

resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.params.prefixDefaultModule = "1"
[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually `xampp` comes with default zend-framework library, that can be found at `C:\xampp\php\pear\zend` or somewhere close to it, and you might have problem due to the version of the zend framework.

Replace this library with your version of library, and you should not have problems (due to versions).

Also you can change the include path of the `php.ini` file.

Comment: i can't find out Zend folder. My XAMPP version is 1.7.3. Anyway i placed Zend folder from mu old project to XAMP\php\perl..But not get . Now got the error message "Warning: simplexml_load_file() [function.simplexml-load-file]: I/O warning : failed to load external entity "../application/config/application.xml" in C:\xampp\php\PEAR\Zend\Config\Xml.php on line 66

Comment: @Testadmin try searching for `zend-framework` in `C:\xampp\php\pear\`. And also make sure that you have file `application.xml` in `/application/config` folder

Comment: you don't need to do anything in php or xampp configuration! just put the zend library in your project folder and set the include path in the application.ini file!

Comment: Ok. Thanks. But from where i will get Application.ini file. Please reply

Comment: @Testadmin well your `application.ini` is in `projdir/application/configs/` ... also it says that you have missing `application.xml` file, just get it from the project you downloaded. it must be in the same location in your proj.